# Who handles the exception for us when we use the keyword "throws"?

Tags: java, exception

When we use "throws" keyword, how an exception is handles and who handles it for us.

Comment: This exceptions will be handled in higher level of your application or in application which use library method throws exception

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `throws` keyword it delegates handling of the Exception to whoever is calling method.  They need to handle in a try-catch or re-throw the Exception.